# Clipping a WebGLTileLayer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, clip, webgl

I want to clip a tile layer against a vector geometry (polygon). When using a canvas renderer, there are somewhat well documented solutions to this using `prerender` and `postrender` event handlers and directly accessing the canvas context.

Now I have a `WebGLTileLayer` and need to clip it the same way, but I can't find any example of how this can be done. There are some examples of clipping against simpler shapes, but not if I have a vector feature with geographic coordinates.

How can I clip a WebGL layer against a feature I have in a `VectorSource`?

Comment: I don't think it can be done directly.  If you must use WebGL (e.g. you have a GeoTIFF) your WebGLTileLayer can be used as a source for a `ol/source/Raster` in an ImageLayer.  You can then clip the ImageLayer in the same way as in the example.